# GCP Monitoring Alert policy

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am attempting to create an alert policy when a metric value drops from 1 to 0. I understand how to set a threshold of below value, but is there a mechanism/logic/condition I can use to set an alert to be triggered if it lowers in value of x amount of minutes?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In the Cloud Console:

1. Go to Monitoring
2. Select Alerting.
3. Click Create policy.
4. Click Add Condition in the Create new alerting policy window.

Target: 
Select Resource Type (VM Instance/Container/etc) 
Metric (CPU Usage/Memory/etc)
Period (Time Interval)

Configuration: 
Condition triggers if 
Condition (**is below** in your case) 
Threshold 
For (select number of minutes)

You can also refer on this [Specifying conditions for alerting policies](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/ui-conditions-ga)  document.

Other metrics/alerting/monitoring [how to guides](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs/how-to) and reference

Comment: I know how to set a threshold, I would need something to only work when a value drops from 1 to 0. Instead of already existing value 0.

Comment: You can set it under configuration of Alert Policy. When your specific metric drops it will trigger an alarm that will notify based on your preferred notification. Can you specify/share what metric value you are referirng for me to replicate?